# How to report a "toxic" player in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

There was an Illidan flaming a Nova in my last game, and I'd like to report him for that. Where can I do so?

Comment: I cant check because i'm not at home but usually you can right click the username in the chat.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the post-game stats screen, there is a gear icon beside each player's name which allows you to create and file a report.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is now an option that better reflects toxic chat, but can be found using this same method.

Answer (score 12):

In the endgame statistics, when you click on statistics you can see all players, when you right click on the specific player the third option counting from below will be the "Report" option there you can select one reason for the report and give a short explanation.

Report will be taken seriusly there are already some banned players for repeatly offending and verbaly atacking other players

Source :
Blizzard customer support

Comment: Damn, beat me to it! If only I hadn't had to play a game just to get the screenshots...

Comment: @Landric: But the screenshots add a ton of value.  When multiple answers that are similar are posted, I usually upvote the first one posted, but if one answer is much more useful, I will vote that one instead, even if it was posted last.