# How do I block a player in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

How do I block communication from a toxic player in Heroes of the Storm? I found a "blocked players" list under ***Options → Social***, but I don't see any way to add new players to the list.

[image: Social options menu]

Comment: See also "[How to report a "Toxic" player in Heroes of the Storm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/212964/181240)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blocking works a bit differently depending on whether you are in a game or not.

---

### During a Game

Open the scoreboard with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, click the Options icon to the far right of a player's name, and select ***Block Communication***.

[image: Blocking player's communication via scoreboard]

### While in a Party

Right click a player's avatar and select ***Block Communication***.

[image: Blocking player in a party]

### While in chat

Right click a player's name or avatar and select ***Block Communication***.

[image: Blocking player in chat]

Comment: To block truly toxic players I recommend "Report Player", which blocks them as well.